# R Summing over Columns and Rows for a Paired Analysis

Tags: r, matrix

One has a spreadsheet where a user inputs the amount of years in the before and after columns. An example is shown below.

[image: SITE Before After Yr_1 Yr_2 Yr_3 Yr_4 Yr_5 Yr_6 Yr_7 1 2 2 4 4 1 5 2 1 1 2 2 5 2 0 0 2 2 0 2 3 1 6 1 0 2 1 0 1 1]

One would like to sum the amount of corresponding years provided in the Yr_1, Yr_2, ... Yr_n rows that correspond to the years in before and after period for each site.

```
df = data.frame(
  SITE = c(1,2,3),
  Before=c(2,2,1),
  After=c(2,5,6),
  Yr_1=c(4,2,1),
  Yr_2=c(4,0,0),
  Yr_3=c(1,0,2),
  Yr_4=c(5,2,1),
  Yr_5=c(2,2,0),
  Yr_6=c(1,0,1),
  Yr_7=c(1,2,1))

df %>% mutate(
  Total_Counts_Before=

ifelse(
  Before == 1, rowSums(across(Yr_1)),
  ifelse(
    Before == 2, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_2)),
    ifelse(
      Before == 3, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_3)),
      ifelse(
        Before == 4, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_4)),
        ifelse(
          Before == 5, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_5)),
          ifelse(
            Before == 6, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_6)),
            ifelse(
              Before == 7, rowSums(across(Yr_1:Yr_7)),"")))))))


)
```

However there can be more than one combination (ie Before_Yr_n x After_Yr_n) so one would need to create a seperate set of 7 columns for After Year Counts in the user table.

[image]

```
df = data.frame(
  SITE = c(1,2,3),
  Before=c(2,2,1),
  After=c(2,5,6),
  Before_Yr_1=c(4,2,1),
  Before_Yr_2=c(4,0,0),
  Before_Yr_3=c(0,0,0),
  Before_Yr_4=c(0,0,0),
  Before_Yr_5=c(0,0,0),
  Before_Yr_6=c(0,0,0),
  Before_Yr_7=c(0,0,0),
  
  After_Yr_1=c(1,0,0),
  After_Yr_2=c(5,2,2),
  After_Yr_3=c(2,2,1),
  After_Yr_4=c(1,0,0),
  After_Yr_5=c(1,2,1),
  After_Yr_6=c(0,0,1),
  After_Yr_7=c(0,0,0)
  
  )
```

```
df = df %>% mutate(
  Total_Counts_Before=

ifelse(
  Before == 1, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1)),
  ifelse(
    Before == 2, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_2)),
    ifelse(
      Before == 3, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_3)),
      ifelse(
        Before == 4, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_4)),
        ifelse(
          Before == 5, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_5)),
          ifelse(
            Before == 6, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_6)),
            ifelse(
              Before == 7, rowSums(across(Before_Yr_1:Before_Yr_7)),""))))))),
  
  Total_Counts_After=
ifelse(
  After == 1, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1)),
  ifelse(
    After == 2, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_2)),
    ifelse(
      After == 3, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_3)),
      ifelse(
        After == 4, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_4)),
        ifelse(
          After == 5, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_5)),
          ifelse(
            After == 6, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_6)),
            ifelse(
              After == 7, rowSums(across(After_Yr_1:After_Yr_7)),"")))))))

)
```

Is there a way one can avoid having the user input data separately into 14 columns or matrix of 3x14 ?

desired output may appear similar to, but must contain Total Before and After Count columns shown below  :

```
library(knitr)
df %>% kable()
```

| SITE | Before | After | Before_Yr_1 | Before_Yr_2 | Before_Yr_3 | Before_Yr_4 | Before_Yr_5 | Before_Yr_6 | Before_Yr_7 | After_Yr_1 | After_Yr_2 | After_Yr_3 | After_Yr_4 | After_Yr_5 | After_Yr_6 | After_Yr_7 | Total_Counts_Before | Total_Counts_After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your data to a long format, then just filter the results you are interested in, I don't know if your concept of after or before includes the current year but you can easily change it

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
  SITE = c(1,2,3),
  Before=c(2,2,1),
  After=c(2,5,6),
  Yr_1=c(4,2,1),
  Yr_2=c(4,0,0),
  Yr_3=c(1,0,2),
  Yr_4=c(5,2,1),
  Yr_5=c(2,2,0),
  Yr_6=c(1,0,1),
  Yr_7=c(1,2,1))


df |> 
  select(-Before,-After) |> 
  pivot_longer(-SITE,names_prefix = 'Yr_',names_to = 'year') |> 
  group_by(SITE) |> 
  mutate(before = cumsum(value),
         before_no_current = cumsum(value) - value,
         after = sum(value) - before_no_current,
         after_no_current = after - value)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 7
#> # Groups:   SITE [3]
#>     SITE year  value before before_no_current after after_no_current
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>             <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1     1 1         4      4                 0    18               14
#>  2     1 2         4      8                 4    14               10
#>  3     1 3         1      9                 8    10                9
#>  4     1 4         5     14                 9     9                4
#>  5     1 5         2     16                14     4                2
#>  6     1 6         1     17                16     2                1
#>  7     1 7         1     18                17     1                0
#>  8     2 1         2      2                 0     8                6
#>  9     2 2         0      2                 2     6                6
#> 10     2 3         0      2                 2     6                6
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: is it possible to pivot_wider back into paired format, so it can be copy and pasted into a word and/or table document. thnx

Comment: Well you usually just join back the results that you want, no need to pivot back

Comment: value column is correct for filtering before counts, however, |> filter(SITE==1 & year==4), filter(SITE==2 & year==5), and filter(SITE==3 & year==7) should provide values 6,6 and and 5 respectively for after counts.